# How I apply two classname at the same time using css module?

Tags: css, css-modules, react-css-modules

I need to apply two classname at the same time using css module and I dont know how.
*When I have invalid input I need that inputs form will be invalid style

```
import style from './Input.module.css';

<div className={style.form_control && ${!inputState.is valid && style.form_control__invalid}}>
</div> 

.form_control{
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.form_control label,
.form_control input,
.form_control p{
  display: block;
  text-align: end;
}

.form_control_invalid label,
.form_control_invalid p {
  color: red;
}

.form_control
__invalid input,
.form_control_invalid textarea {
  border-color: red;
  background: #ffd1d1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div 
    className={`${style.form_control} ${!inputState.isValid && 
        style.form_control__invalid}`}>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can chain css classes like this:

```
.firstclass.secondclass {
  // styling comes here
}
```

In your case it can be like this:

```
.form_control.form_control_invalid label,
.form_control.form_control_invalid p {
  color: red;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

If not, please declare further.